# Get contents of element without escaping in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get contents of element **without** any changes. When I using .html(), it unnecessarily escapes characters, for example `&` to `&amp;`.

In my code, Content is data come from server. Problem is the original data has been escaped. I also don't want to use unescaping process. It means 2 time change the original data.

Any idea would be very appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:blue; margin:8px; }
  b { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><b>Hey, Give me originial HTML contents</b>, "& < >" without any escapes. pls</p>
  <p></p>
<script>
var str = $("p:first").html();
$("p:last").text(str);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: 
As mentioned above, I need data without changes. HTML tags too. I know what .text() does.

EDIT2:
**str** must be exactly. `<b>Hey, Give me originial HTML contents</b>, "& < >" without any escapes. pls`. Please understand the question is **not about how to display** it correctly. Variable **str** must hold correct(original) data.

Comment: "it unnecessarily escapes characters" is untrue. It is invalid to have a bare `&`; the browser is merely trying to guess what you mean, and it changed it into what it thought it actually was. `&amp;` is the correct form, and if the browser doesn't want to think about a bare `&`, it won't.

Answer (score 4):

You should use same combination:-

```
var str = $("p:first").html();
$("p:last").html(str);
```

or

```
var str = $("p:first").text();
$("p:last").text(str);
```

Or if you want to display the tags as is you will have to escape the "<", ">" , "&" etc

```
var  str = $('p:first').html();
str = str.replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
$("p:last").html(str);
```

Comment: what if the OP want is to print the content so the `p:first` in screen not to render it

Comment: from what I understood he want to display `<b>Hey, Give me originial HTML contents</b>, "& < >" without any escapes. pls` in the second `p`

Comment: Thank you for reply @PSL. $("p:last").text(str); is just using for display results.

Comment: @TuvshinGongor You want to display result or display the html with tags as is?

Comment: @PSL Displaying result is for debugging. It's not about to display. We can use `alert(str);` instead of `$("p:last").text(str);`. **str must be exactly** `<b>Hey, Give me originial HTML contents</b>, "& < >" without any escapes. pls`. **Not** `<b>Hey, Give me originial HTML contents</b>, "&amp; &lt; &gt;" without any escapes. pls`

Comment: @TuvshinGongor Check my answer and this fiddle.

Comment: @PSL your 3rd solution displays text correctly. **But**  If you debug your code, str would be `&lt;b&gt;Hey, Give me originial HTML contents&lt;/b&gt;, "&amp; &lt; &gt;" without any escapes. pls`. My question is not about how to display text correctly. It's about how to get original content as it written. I'm trying to find solution without additional unescape(or escape) processes. That changes data again, and again.

Comment: Yes of-course that is how it will appear in HTML.  If X-html you can put it inside cData, but i am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("p:last").text(str);
```

to

```
$("p:last").html(str);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRTwc/)**

Comment: For above code it works , what if he uses as string for some other operations...???

Answer (score 0):

below code works fine to copy innerhtml as is into another element.
[Jquery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boraganesh/vPqpn/)

```
var str = $("p:first").innerHtml();
$("p:last").text(str);
```